# Rewrite correlated subquery, Redshift throwing This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet Error

Tags: sql, left-join, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

I'm working on a query that needs to left join table A with table B on A.user_id=B.user_id and B.day is less than A.day but is closest to A.day.

Here's what I wrote:

```
Select A.user_id, A.date, b1.v1 from A
Left Join B as b1
on A.user_id=b1.user_id and b1.day=(Select max(day) from B as b2 where b2.user_id=A.user_id
and b2.day < A.day)
```

I'm doing this in python using psycopg2 and it's returning error: `This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet`.

Can someone help me rewrite this so it doesn't use correlated subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this can be:

```
Select A.user_id, A.date, b1.v1, max(b1.day) 
from A Left Join B as b1 on A.user_id=b1.user_id and b1.day < A.day 
group by A.user_id, A.date, b1.v1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is rather expensive, but . . . :

```
select . . .
from (select A.user_id, A.date, b1.v1,
             row_number() over (partition by a.user_id, a.date order by b.day desc) as seqnum
      from A Left Join
           B 
          on A.user_id = b1.user_id and b.day < a.day
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```

There may be other ways to accomplish this -- and that have better performance.  If that is needed, ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.